# Toggling showing and hiding between two elements

Tags: angular

I have a tabs nav element that has two tabs, it needs to show a component based on what tab was clicked and hide the other component.  If the clicked tab is already "active", the component needs to remain showing.

I have this working, but it seems very inefficient to me.  Can anyone show me a better way to do this?

Here's how I have it set up now.  For the sake of not posting every file in the question, know that the project is set up correctly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="changeShowStatus(oneShowing=true,twoShowing=false)">1</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="changeShowStatus(twoShowing=true,oneShowing=false)">2</button>
      <div class="box1" *ngIf="oneShowing">
        <p>some content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box2" *ngIf="twoShowing">
        <p>some content2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  oneShowing:boolean;
  twoShowing:boolean

  constructor() {
    this.oneShowing = true;
    this.twoShowing = false
  }
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8BmzHPULt2wTwXrQUnfh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <div>
  <button type="button" (click)="activeIndex = 1">1</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="activeIndex = 2">2</button>
  <div class="box1" *ngIf="activeIndex === 1">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2" *ngIf="activeIndex === 2">
    <p>some content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  activeIndex = 0;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way to do it.

1.Initialize `currentContent` variable to default content value.

2.On click of a button set its value to desired content.

3.Show the div if `currentContent` matches the desiredValue.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="currentContent='content1'">1</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="currentContent='content2'">2</button>
      <div class="box1" *ngIf="currentContent==='content1'">
        <p>some content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box2" *ngIf="currentContent==='content2'">
        <p>some content2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
    name: string;
    currentContent: string = "content1"; //default tab

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to use brodcasting events. In this create a observable  brodcaster and brodcast message to close other popups when any one popup is about to open. https://blog.lacolaco.net/post/event-broadcasting-in-angular-2/ use it when multiple date pickers or drop-down are present at webpage and need to open one at a time. I used it, very helpful for making comment type of drop-down.